# Select two tables when one table is empty or not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have stucked to figuring out what's wrong with my query. i select table 'acara' and table 'eventorg', 
if table 'acara' not found or empty, 
table 'eventorg' dont want to show up, 
but if table 'acara' not empty or found, 
table 'eventorg' and table 'acara' will show up

it is my query

```
SELECT 
  eventorg.nama as NamaEO,
  eventorg.deskripsi as DeskEO,
  eventorg.logo as LogoEO,
  eventorg.email as EmailEO,
  eventorg.telp as TelpEO,
  acara.nama as NamaEvent,    
  acara.id_acara,
  acara.tanggal,
  acara.deskripsi,
  acara.lokasi
FROM eventorg 
LEFT JOIN acara 
ON acara.id_eo=eventorg.id_eo AND eventorg.id_eo='$ideventO';
```

'id_eo' in table 'eventorg' is primary key, 'id_eo' in table 'acara' is foreign key

Comment: Read this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thank you @MatthewHerbst, it really helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select every row of `eventorg` regardless of whether a corresponding record in `acara` exists, then you need a RIGHT JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN (or reverse the tables in your FROM and LEFT JOIN clauses).

As Matthew referenced in his comment, Jeff Atwood's Venn diagrams are nice way to visualize it: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/